# How to query @JoinTable in Spring Data Jpa？

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I used the Type filter in BookRepository, but it's not work.

Book.java

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "book_type",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
    )
    private Type type;

    // getter and setter
}
```

Type.java

```
@Entity
public class Type {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "book_type",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "type_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    )
    private Collection<Book> books;

    // getter and setter
}
```

BookRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {
    Page<Book> findBookListByType(Type type, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Is not Spring Data Jpa does not support this feature.

Comment: Why not DEFINE what query you want to perform? What needs to be returned with what constraints? No idea why people think of some join table ... you query the ENTITY and relations, this is not SQL land

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

    @Query(value="Select b from Book b where b.type = :type")
    Page<Book> findAllByType(@Param("type") Type type, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Comment: I guess you want all the books with a specific type!??

Comment: I have different books, which are different types. Now no matter what type I choose, it will show all the books.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have one `@OneToMany` associations, you can change the FetchType to EAGER.